# Azure Umbraco Web Matrix Publish Error

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, umbraco, webmatrix

I am having an issue installing Umbraco via webmatrix to Azure.

Here is the Error:

```
> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

I can't find anything online to help fix this problem. It's a pretty basic Umbraco install with only one plugin: Nested Content.

Here is the Full Stack Trace:

```
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The
> located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
> reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]   
> System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
> throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
> StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
> loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0   
> System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
> throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
> StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
> loadTypeFromPartialName) +70    System.RuntimeType.GetType(String
> typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean
> reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +40   
> System.Type.GetType(String typeName) +30   
> System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DataRow providerRow)
> +108    System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName) +88   
> Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Database.CommonConstruct() +35   
> Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Database..ctor(String connectionString,
> String providerName) +119   
> Umbraco.Core.DatabaseContext.ValidateDatabaseSchema() +211   
> Umbraco.Core.ApplicationContext.get_IsUpgrading() +68   
> Umbraco.Web.Security.Identity.AppBuilderExtensions.UseUmbracoBackOfficeCookieAuthentication(IAppBuilder
> app, CookieAuthenticationOptions options, ApplicationContext
> appContext, PipelineStage stage) +96   
> Umbraco.Web.Security.Identity.AppBuilderExtensions.UseUmbracoBackOfficeCookieAuthentication(IAppBuilder
> app, ApplicationContext appContext, PipelineStage stage) +314   
> Umbraco.Web.UmbracoDefaultOwinStartup.ConfigureMiddleware(IAppBuilder
> app) +30   
> Umbraco.Web.UmbracoDefaultOwinStartup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
> +44
> 
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
> an invocation.]    System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object
> target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0   
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
> Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +160   
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> +101    Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass12.<MakeDelegate>b__b(IAppBuilder builder) +66   
> Owin.Loader.<>c__DisplayClass1.<LoadImplementation>b__0(IAppBuilder
> builder) +123   
> Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.<>c__DisplayClass2.<InitializeBlueprint>b__0(IAppBuilder
> builder) +71   
> Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action`1
> startup) +462   
> Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup) +40 
> Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint() +70
> System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target,
> Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +115   
> Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication
> context) +106   
> System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
> appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +536   
> System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
> MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172   
> System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
> appContext, HttpContext context) +336   
> System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
> appContext) +296
> 
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target
> of an invocation.]   
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9963380 
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
> +101    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
> wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll are not loaded correctly. From my experience, it may be the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll file not in the bin folder or not config correctly in the web.config file.  We can check the file in the project locally and use [kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-the-kudu-service) tools to check the files in the Azure portal.  More detail please refer to the screenshot.I also find some materials about [How to installing Umbraco with Microsoft WebMatrix](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/setup/install/install-umbraco-with-microsoft-webmatrix).

[image]

[image]

If there is no this setting in Web.config, please add it in the Web.config file.

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" name="Microsoft® SQL Server® Compact 4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```